# Parse an array of RegEx from string

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have a component using react with [`masked-input`](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/react#readme). This component uses an array of RegEx to work:

```js
import React from 'react'
import MaskedInput from 'react-text-mask'

export default () => (
  <div>
    <MaskedInput
      mask={['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]}
    />
  </div>
)
```

I fetch the mask value from a remote API, the mask comes as a string:

```js
var mask = '[/d/, /d/, " / ", /d/, /d/, " / ", /d/, /d/, /d/, /d/]'
```

How I can transform this string to a valid array of RegEx and strings?

From

```js
var mask = '[/d/, /d/, " / ", /d/, /d/, " / ", /d/, /d/, /d/, /d/]'
```

to

```js
var mask = [/d/, /d/, " / ", /d/, /d/, " / ", /d/, /d/, /d/, /d/]
```

Comment: Do you have control of the remote server? An easier way would be to modify the server to return all strings then JSON.parse the result.

Comment: @Marie JSON doesn't know what a regex is, so parsing it won't produce regex objects.

Comment: @VLAZ That was why I said have the server return all strings if they have control. Then you could `JSON.parse(mask).map(s => new RegExp(s))` and be on your way, no hacking/manually parsing required.

Comment: @Marie but `" / "` -> `" / "`, not `/ \/ /`

Comment: those are both the same thing. `/ \/ /.test(" / ") === new RegExp(" / ").test(" / ") // true`. Either way it doesnt matter if OP controls the server, they can tweak things to work. Which is why I asked that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make a loop for each item and put them to [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) class:

```js
var mask = '[/d/, /d/, " / ", /d/, /d/, " / ", /d/, /d/, /d/, /d/]';

mask = mask.substring(1, mask.length - 1);

var patterns = [];

for (var pattern of mask.split(',')) {
  pattern = pattern.trim().replace(/(^\/)|(\/$)|(^")|("$)/g, '');
  
  patterns.push(new RegExp(`${pattern}`));
}

console.log(patterns);
console.log(patterns[0].test('d'));
```

---

If you want to keep the item which contains `" / "` as a string, not a regex pattern. In side the loop, you can edit it to:

```
for (var pattern of mask.split(',')) {
  pattern = pattern.trim().replace(/(^\/)|(\/$)/g, '');

  patterns.push(/^".+"$/.test(pattern) ? pattern.replace(/"/g, '') : new RegExp(`${pattern}`));
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `" / "` produce a *string* not the regex `/ \/ /`?

Answer (score 0):

you can slice the string and then convert it to an array then use `new RegExp` to convert each element into a regex :

```js
var mask = '[/d/, /d/, " / ", /d/, /d/, " / ", /d/, /d/, /d/, /d/]';

const arrayRegex = mask.slice(1, mask.length - 1).split(",").map(reg => new RegExp(reg.trim()));



console.log(arrayRegex);
```

Comment: `" / "` is supposed to be a literal string, not the regular expression for this value. Also, `/d/` should probably not include the `/` symbols as they denote a regular expression literal (and otherwise notation for a regex).

Comment: @VLAZ Does it make sense to differentiate between a literal string and a regular expression when the regular expression is literal?

Comment: @Marie the two are in no way similar, so I'm not sure what the question is. According to OP a string should be a string, while a regex should be a regex. Unless the information in the question is incorrect, I don't see why you'd generate a regex for a literal `" / "`.

Answer (score 0):

Because your string includes the enclosing brackets, the simplest way to convert your string to an array of regular expressions is:

```
var arr = eval(mask);
```

You can then test your values this way:

```
arr[0].test('d')
true
arr[0].test('e')
false
```

This method will leave your " / " entries as strings.